# Human assisted handicapped engine against engine, adjustable parameters

Tags: engines, software

I am looking for software preferably local interface on windows, to play  human+engine against engine with access to search parameters such as depth and "greed" or dismissal factor (controlling pruning).

One side would have an engine proposing moves to a human player against another usually stronger engine. This could be the same engine with better parameters choices.

Open source preferred, engine could be Stockfish, but I am more looking for the interface that would allow such games, human interaction at each move, and compilation of data from those games.  GUI preferred but CLI is okay if it is the only solution.

Also, if existing software that can handle engine on one side could be modded to be bi-directional that way, with pause at each turn, that would be something I could work with (some SDK allowing that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyChess](https://pychess.github.io/) is a graphical interface for chess that has the features you describe (or at least PyChess Philidor, its predecessor, used to have them). It allows you to load multiple engines, to choose between their suggestions, it supports human vs computer games as well as depth and pruning, it is open source, etcetera. Just to be clear, PyChess does not come with a default engine, you have to install the engine separately and then load it when you open PyChess.

Unfortunately it was not the most intuitive software, at least not for me, so I stopped using it.

Comment: best answer so far.... thanks.